# Getting Null Value When Input List Files in Asp .Net Core with Mediatr

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, file-upload, mediatr

I get null value when debug request files. Here my codes:

My controller:

```
    [ProducesResponseType(type: typeof(ReturnDigitalClaimVm), statusCode: StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [HttpPost(template: "createclaim")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateClaimDC(
        [FromBody] CreateClaimCommand reqdata, 
        [FromForm] IEnumerable<IFormFile> files)
    {
        var command = new ClaimCommand()
        {
            CommandBody = reqdata,
            Files = files
        };
        return Wrapper(val: await Mediator.Send(request: command));
    }
```

My models:

```
public class ReturnDigitalClaimVm
{
    public string DocId { get; set; }
}

public class ClaimCommand : IRequest<ReturnDigitalClaimVm>
{
    public CreateClaimCommand CommandBody { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<IFormFile> Files { get; set; }
}

public class CreateClaimCommand 
{
    public string AWB { get; set; }
}
```

My CommandHandler:

```
public class CreateClaimCommandHandler : IRequestHandler<ClaimCommand, ReturnDigitalClaimVm>
{
   public async Task<ReturnDigitalClaimVm> Handle(ClaimCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var checkReqBody = request.CommandBody.AWB;
        var checkReqFiles = request.Files; //--> I debug my code here
        
        return new ReturnDigitalClaimVm
        {
            DocId = "XXX-123"
        };
    }
}
```

My inputs from swagger:
[image: inputs from swagger]

My debug:

[image: debug]

When I debug my code in CommandHandler at var checkReqBody, I get value "test" but at "**var checkReqFiles**" I get null value even though I had put two files form swagger. I tried change `IEnumerable<IFormFile> files` to `List<IFormFile> files` in controller and model, but I get same result. Could anyone help me?

Comment: In the controller, **files** have value?

Comment: in controller, files is null

Comment: Then your problem is not MediatR. Check the solution proposed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your request code like this

```
public class ReturnDigitalClaimVm
{
    public string DocId { get; set; }
}

public class ClaimCommand : IRequest<ReturnDigitalClaimVm>
{
    public string AWB { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<IFormFile> Files { get; set; }
}
```

You cannot use [FormBody] and [FromFrom] in the same time, if you want receive file and text in your request model, you can use [FromForm] with multipart/form-data content type.

```
[ProducesResponseType(type: typeof(ReturnDigitalClaimVm), statusCode: StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[HttpPost(template: "createclaim")]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateClaimDC( 
    [FromForm] ClaimCommand  request)
{
    return Wrapper(val: await Mediator.Send(request: request));
}
```

[postman request body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLlgE.png)

Make sure in your rest client request using multipart/form-data.
Hope it's clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can not have [FromForm] and [FromBody] at the same time.
Both of them receive data from HTTP Request body but [FromBody] means it's in json format and [FromForm] means it's url encoded or it's in multipart format.